# Where can I find pictures of "endplate"?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics

Where can it possible to find pictures or drawings of "endplate"? (for "winglet" is much easier, but not endplate)

I'm asking what's written above, after I read the following text from Raymer and I need a better comprehension of it.

> The wing aspect ratio "$A$" is the geometric aspect ratio of the
>   complete reference planform. the effective aspect ratio will be
>   increased by wing endplates or winglets
>
> Endplate: $A_{effective} = A(1+1.9\frac{h}{b})$ - (12.10)   where $h$ = endplate height
>
> Winglet: $A_{effective} = \approx 1.2A$  -     (12.11)
>
> These effective aspect ratios should also be used in the induced drag
>   calculations below. note that Eq. (12.11) for winglets is a crude
>   approximation based upon limited data for wings of moderate aspect
>   ratio

......................

> The extra drag due to non-elliptical lift distribution and the flow
>   separation can be accounted for using e, the "Oswald span efficiency
>   factor". This effectively reduces the aspect ratio, producing the
>   following equation for $K$
>
> $K=\frac{1}{πAe}$ (12.48)
>
> If the wing has end-plates or winglets, the effective aspect ratio
>   from Eq. (12.10) or (12.11) should be used in Eq. (12.48)

(Source: Daniel P. Raymer "Aircraft design . A conceptual approach" , Chapter 12 Aerodynamics)

Comment: The endplate that i think the OP is referring to is the the part that maintenance attaches to the wing to cover the end of the wing when a wingtip is removed, due to damage for example.

Answer (score 3):

I seem to remember that wing end plates were sometimes used on Short Take Off and Landing(STOL) aircraft in the 1960's.

I found a few photos while doing an internet search but they seem to be much more prevalent on race car wings these days.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is an explanation of why end plates are used on race cars: [Analysis: Rear Wing Endplates](http://thewptformula.com/2013/08/13/analysis-rear-wing-endplates/)

> The endplate has two functions, the primary reason for their shape is
>   to control the wingtip vortices at the trailing edge of the wing as
>   this reduces drag and also lift. The second reason is that they
>   control how the airflow makes its way over, under or around the
>   aerofoil device that is creating the downforce on the car, resulting
>   in better airflow management and maximising the performance of the
>   component.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Winglets and aerodynamic endplates are in the category of "wingtip devices". Try searching for "wingtip device" + fence or endplate